# Chromium scrolling lag on Raspberry Pi 3 Model B running Raspbian Stretch

Tags: chromium

I received my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B a few days ago, I copied Raspbian Stretch `img` with `dd` to 64 GB Samsung EVO card.

I am using a HDMI to VGA adapter on a 1920x1080 Samsung monitor. 
Also, I have enabled G1 GL Full KMS via `raspi-config`
I have also increased GPU memory from 64 MB to 256 MB.

I have enabled following in Chrome flags:

```
Override software rendering list
GPU rasterization 
Zero-copy rasterizer
```

I run Chromium with:

```
chromium-browser --enable-native-gpu-memory-buffers --enable-features="CheckerImaging"
```

**For first day use I didn't have any problems**, I had **smooth 1080p youtube playback and browsing scrolling was fine**.
Today I started Chromium and I noticed lag while scrolling.

I have tried rebooting several times and re-applying configuration like GPU memory, GL...

I even tried reinstalling mesa drivers, running `rpi-update`
I think `dmesg` clearly shows the problem but I can't understand it:

```
[  200.278732] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[  200.278791] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 483 at drivers/gpu/drm/vc4/vc4_plane.c:756 vc4_plane_async_set_fb+0xa4/0xa8 [vc4]
[  200.278794] Modules linked in: fuse rfcomm bnep hci_uart btbcm bluetooth panel_raspberrypi_touchscreen joydev evdev vc4 drm_kms_helper brcmfmac drm brcmutil snd_soc_core snd_compress snd_pcm_dmaengine syscopyarea cfg80211 sysfillrect sysimgblt i2c_gpio snd_bcm2835 fb_sys_fops i2c_algo_bit rfkill snd_pcm snd_timer snd i2c_bcm2835 bcm2835_gpiomem uio_pdrv_genirq uio fixed sg i2c_dev ip_tables x_tables ipv6
[  200.278890] CPU: 0 PID: 483 Comm: Xorg Not tainted 4.9.59-v7+ #1047
[  200.278893] Hardware name: BCM2835
[  200.278916] [<8010fb3c>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<8010c058>] (show_stack+0x20/0x24)
[  200.278926] [<8010c058>] (show_stack) from [<80456764>] (dump_stack+0xd4/0x118)
[  200.278938] [<80456764>] (dump_stack) from [<8011d348>] (__warn+0xf8/0x110)
[  200.278947] [<8011d348>] (__warn) from [<8011d430>] (warn_slowpath_null+0x30/0x38)
[  200.278983] [<8011d430>] (warn_slowpath_null) from [<7f4aeb5c>] (vc4_plane_async_set_fb+0xa4/0xa8 [vc4])
[  200.279057] [<7f4aeb5c>] (vc4_plane_async_set_fb [vc4]) from [<7f4aec2c>] (vc4_update_plane+0xcc/0x154 [vc4])
[  200.279260] [<7f4aec2c>] (vc4_update_plane [vc4]) from [<7f34ef4c>] (__setplane_internal+0x190/0x238 [drm])
[  200.279530] [<7f34ef4c>] (__setplane_internal [drm]) from [<7f34f114>] (drm_mode_cursor_universal+0x120/0x1bc [drm])
[  200.279765] [<7f34f114>] (drm_mode_cursor_universal [drm]) from [<7f34f23c>] (drm_mode_cursor_common+0x8c/0x194 [drm])
[  200.279994] [<7f34f23c>] (drm_mode_cursor_common [drm]) from [<7f34f8ec>] (drm_mode_cursor2_ioctl+0x18/0x1c [drm])
[  200.280228] [<7f34f8ec>] (drm_mode_cursor2_ioctl [drm]) from [<7f332c60>] (drm_ioctl+0x20c/0x428 [drm])
[  200.280373] [<7f332c60>] (drm_ioctl [drm]) from [<80283b74>] (do_vfs_ioctl+0xac/0x820)
[  200.280385] [<80283b74>] (do_vfs_ioctl) from [<8028432c>] (SyS_ioctl+0x44/0x6c)
[  200.280399] [<8028432c>] (SyS_ioctl) from [<801080c0>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x1c)
[  200.280405] ---[ end trace 81688151713e1c56 ]---
```

This is my config.txt

```
# For more options and information see
# http://rpf.io/configtxt
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment this if your display has a black border of unused pixels visible
# and your display can output without overscan
#disable_overscan=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=82

# Tells the Pi to ignore everything that the monitor is telling it about the resolution it can run at
hdmi_ignore_edid=0xa5000080

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
config_hdmi_boost=7

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
#dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
#dtparam=spi=on

# Uncomment this to enable the lirc-rpi module
#dtoverlay=lirc-rpi

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on
gpu_mem=256
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
#dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
```

Also here is my `chrome://gpu`

[image]

```
uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.9.59-v7+ #1047 SMP Sun Oct 29 12:19:23 GMT 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Comment: It seems the cause is OpenGL, when I disable it chromium works better (i set to legacy) but stilla after that chrome://gpu shows that webgl 1 and 2 is hw optimized, which is crazy?! (How if it's disabled).
I tested opengl when its enabled with glxgears and I get 60fps, i do not understand why does it slow chromium down? Does anyone have answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8462421/differences-between-webgl-and-opengl

Still confused

Comment: Did you find the solution to the problem? Scrolls with OpenGL disabled seems smoother than with gpu in my case too

Comment: No i havent ...

Comment: This answer fixed the scrolling issue for me. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/83113/webgl-does-not-work-properly-on-raspberry-pi-chromium-browser

Comment: You need to run ```sudo apt update && sudo apt -y dist-upgrade``` your kernel is a long way out of date. If you're running on Jessie, you'll need to update to 2018-11-13 Stretch first.

Comment: Do you see the date of this post? :)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. Try turning off smooth scrolling. It worked for me  (it's a setting in your browser. Chrome in this case)

chrome://flags/#smooth-scrolling

Answer (score 0):

**you need to change the gpu_mem in the config file to 128**. at least that is  what worked for me *and i know you posted this question 2 and a half years ago but maybe other people have the same problem and can benefit from this.*