# WebGL does not work properly on Raspberry Pi Chromium Browser

Tags: chromium, gpu

I have a problem with WebGL on Raspberry Pi 3's Chromium browser. I did the settings required but nothing happened.

Here is my information

- **Device :** Raspberry Pi 3
- **OS :** Linux raspberrypi 4.9.80-v7+ #1098 SMP Fri Mar 9 19:11:42 GMT 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux(Raspian Stretch with desktop, i also try lite)
- **Browser :** chromium-browser version => Chromium 60.0.3112.89 Built on Ubuntu 14.04, running on Raspbian 9.3
- **Graphics Driver :** vc4-kms-v3d

Here are the get.webgl.org results:

[image: get.webgl.org results]

Here is the threejs.org example ("webgl_animation_cloth") results:

[image: threejs.org example "webgl_animation_cloth" results]

I tested the same websites on firefox iceweasel.
They work as shown by these screenshots:

[image: get.webgl.org results(iceweasel)]

[image: threejs.org example "webgl_animation_cloth" results(iceweasel)]

I tried several settings on chrome://flags but nothing is changed

When I start `chromium-browser` from the command line, I see

```
libgl error: MESA-LOADER: failed to retrieve device information
```

but @eric-anholt say this should not have important effects.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me. Reported it to the chromium guys yet?

Comment: I edited the question, it gives me this error : MESA-LOADER: failed to retrieve device information. I try to execute glxgears command in order to test mesa, it gives the same error but it works, so i get confused :(

Comment: That's just noise from some code that's bad at ARM platforms.  It's not a signal that anything is broken.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay so I found a solution here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=191087

> 1. use raspi-config to enable OpenGL (Full KMS)
> 2. remove "--disable-gpu-compositing'' from /etc/chromium-browser/customizations/00-rpi-var
>
> is all you need to do to get the https://get.webgl.org cube spinning.

Works for me!

Comment: AS you see the firefox screenshots,OpenGL(Full KMS or Fake KMS) is enabled, and i try the flags. I think this is the interesting part, everything seems like legal but, the cube is not shown!!

Comment: @MehmetBayrak did you try editing the file as stated in my answer? I am not using any flags.

Comment: Yes!, you are right when i edited "/etc/chromium-browser/customizations/00-rpi-var", it works! thanks

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your not the only one with this problem. You might wanna check your `chrome://flash` page , and see if you are using any drivers that you shouldn't. Test and check each driver accordingly for function. Afterwards, uninstall then reinstall  chromium to see if anything has changed:

```
sudo apt remove chromium-browser
rm -rf ~/.cache/chromium
rm -rf ~/.config/chromium
sudo rm -rf /etc/chromium-browser
```

If this solution doesn't work...

Most people report the issue to do with their graphics card, you can see this issue by going to `chrome://gpu/` and seeing if hardware acceleration is enabled for WebGL. If it is not, this likely because chromium has blacklisted the RPi's GPU; which is why you are getting the following prompt

```
**failed to retrieve device information**
```

because your Pi's GPU has been blacklisted. You will have to find a way to get Chromium to start while ignoring the blacklist. I do know that for Google Chrome the command is

```
google-chrome --enable-webgl --ignore-gpu-blacklist
```

So you might wanna try something similar for Chromium.

In the meanwhile, use Firefox if you can, and check the [link here](https://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/BlacklistsAndWhitelists) discussing blacklists on WebGL, you may also want to report this as a bug to the developers.

**----UPDATE----**

The following command should fix your problem:

```
chromium-browser --enable-webgl --ignore-gpu-blacklist
```

Comment: I need chromium-browser on my rpi, i cannot use firefox. I think it is a bug. I already try reinstall chromium and also with --ignore-gpu-blacklist flag and it is not work again. I check the chrome://flash. GL_RENDERER : **Gallium 0.4 on VC4 V3D 2.1** and GL_VERSION : **2.1 Mesa 13.0.6**. Others seem normal.

Comment: just a thought i didn't find this anywhere: maybe you could download an older version of chromium and test this again, if it is a bug, it is entirely possible that an older model of chromium should work fine.

Comment: IT WORKED! IT WORKED! running `chromium-browser --enable-webgl --ignore-gpu-blacklist` returns a ton of errors, but it starts chromium and the `get.webgl.org` works!

Answer (score 1):

I found that the following works for "Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)":
*To find out which version you have type "cat /etc/os-release" in a terminal.*

1. Console: sudo raspi-config
   Under "7 Advanced Options" / "A7 GL Driver" pick "G2 GL (Fake KMS)"
2. Desktop: Preferences / Add Remove Software
   search for "Chrome" and pick "WebDriver driver for the Chromium Browser", click "OK"